# Why can't I read comments on a locked answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, locked

I saw this note on an [answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/99969/10372) today:

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

I totally understand locking preventing edits and new comments etc, but why can't I even read (out of morbid curiosity at least) the comments that made it before the lock?

Comment: You can't read those comments because they were deleted. They were not relevant to the post, were just noise and were removed as such.

Comment: @Oded as an aside on that question... if the comments are gone, then a mod should probably remove the text responding to the comments. *I respect your opinion and simply ask that you not come here asking questions about why you are not able to find a job* It's a bit... rough, perhaps? Without knowing the context of the removed comments, that is.

Comment: [So tempting, sometimes.](https://imgur.com/a/LYE5c)

Comment: Making morbid things disappear is what moderators are for; if morbid curiosity is left unsatisfied, then they did their job.

Answer (score 5):

As Oded noted in comments, it's rather common for moderators to clean up the comments that led to locking a post prior to applying the lock. This is usually because they noticed a bunch of comment flags in the moderation dashboard (where they probably deleted the worst of them) and then visited the post to see what else was needed.

It's sometimes easy to overlook a comment or two after cleaning things up that now seems out of place once the offending comments were removed; if you notice this just flag those comments as no longer needed and they'll get cleaned up.

The reason for locking is shown more specifically to let folks know what we're hoping to avoid once the post is unlocked, even though it does a great job of telling folks why we locked it :) We'd rather tell folks to slow down and be careful rather than leave a bunch of sensational wreckage at the side of the road, so to say.